# implementing UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForETH failed

Tags: smartcontracts

following the [Smart Contract Integration / Implement a Swap](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/trading-from-a-smart-contract/), my contact likes below

```
contract UniDemo {
    function swapTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline)  public payable returns(uint) {
        // transfer
        require(Token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn), 'transferFrom failed.');
        // approve
        require(Token.approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountIn), 'approve failed.');
        // swap
        uint[] memory outs = uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(amountIn, amountOutMin, getPathForTokenToETH(), msg.sender, deadline);

        return outs[1];
  }
}
```

I keep getting EVM revert error, Is this something wrong?

Example tx: [0x080555abe5287a8e7d67a9129e9464d2773955371fd9ffcf6e81b301d0a7f4df](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x080555abe5287a8e7d67a9129e9464d2773955371fd9ffcf6e81b301d0a7f4df)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not receiving any response from the router (uniswapRouter), so return `outs[1]` throws a revert error as your `outs` array is empty.